# change image on click jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, click

I have this jQuery slide code-
EDIT-Sorry guys grabbed the wrong code :/ heres the actually code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();  
        $('.secondarytitle').click(function() {  
           $(this).closest('tr').siblings('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(); 
        });  
     });

</script>
```

I have to images for the click function, which will be a

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="image1">Welcome</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is when the object is clicked it changes the image, once clicked again it will change back to the original image. Any suggestions will work for me. Even if you suggest a different code to slide the content. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach

```
var imgSRC={'src1':'URL_1','src2': 'URL_2' }

$('.image1').click(function(){
   if($(this).attr('src')==imgSRC.src1){
       $(this).attr('src',imgSRC.src2)
   }else{
       $(this).attr('src',imgSRC.src1)
   }
})
```

Comment: imgSRC is that where i write the src of the img? and could i place this in the jQuery i have above or should i make a new one?

Comment: yes, imgSRC contains urls of images, It allows you avoid spending time in the future to edit image`s url. In this case all urls will be placed in one place

Comment: ooooo ok i see where url_1 is. so i dont type anything in the section of ('src',imgSRC.src1) but instead type it in the var imgSRC={'src1':'/imagesrc.png','src2':'/imagesrc2.png'} just want to make sure, I was about to edit the first thing i said :X

Answer (score 2):

just a slight change in Anton's answer. you can use `toggle()` method not requiring to check img src

```
var imgSRC={'src1':'URL_1','src2': 'URL_2' }

$('.image1').toggle(function(){
      $(this).attr('src',imgSRC.src2)
   }, function() {
       $(this).attr('src',imgSRC.src1)
   }
});
```